# WPF ListView doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have been experiencing problems with WPF `ListView` (using elements binding), as I tried to initialize it by injecting `ItemsSource` the list of Disks, and got no visual feedback from the element. I wrote my code using the example supplied [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/).

Here are the relevant code parts:

**Setting the ListView**

```
    private void viewDisk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<DiskDetails> data = new List<DiskDetails>();
        foreach(Disk disk in disks)            
            data.Add(new DiskDetails(disk.GetVolumeHeader().DiskName, disk.GetVolumeHeader().DiskOwner,disk.GetVolumeHeader().ProdDate));               
        disksList.ItemsSource = data;
    }
```

**DiskDetails Class**

```
public class DiskDetails
    {
        public string diskName { get; set; }
        public string diskOwner { get; set; }
        public string cDate { get; set; }
        public DiskDetails(string dN, string dO,string cD)
        {
            diskName = dN;
            diskOwner = dO;
            cDate = cD;
        }
    }
```

**WPF ListView**

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <ListView x:Name="disksList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="250" SelectionChanged="disksList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Disk Name" Width="108" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Disk Owner" Width="108" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Creation Date" Width="108" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="viewDisk" Content="View Disk" Width="90" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,15" Click="viewDisk_Click"/>
    </Grid>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your DisplayMemberBinding wasn't changed from the example code. Try changing the bindings to match the properties of DiskDetails. E.g. DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" should change to DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding diskName}"